# Specifying application name in log4net when using Loggly

Tags: asp.net, log4net, loggly

I have a couple of ASP.NET web applications I am testing and have set them up with Loggly using their appender for Log4net.

Now, logging seems to be fine but I can't seem to find a way (using log4 loggly appender) to specify an application name so that when I am at Loggly's dashboard I can filter them out and see only the logs of a particular application.

Answer (score 3):

You can't specify an application name using HTTP/S Event Endpoint (Loggly log4net appender uses it inside), this feature is available only for syslog. ([Here is the answer on this issue from Loggly support](https://loggly.desk.com/customer/portal/questions/5521008-how-do-i-send-host-and-application-using-loggly-api))

You should use [Tags](https://www.loggly.com/docs/tags/) to limit your searches to specific groups of related logs.
You can specify tags in config file using UserAgent property:

```
<appender name="LogglyAppender" type="log4net.loggly.LogglyAppender, log4net-loggly">
    <rootUrl value="https://logs-01.loggly.com/" />
    <inputKey value="********-****-****-****-************" />
    <userAgent value="TagOne,TagTwo,TagThree" />
</appender>
```

Comment: You have to separate the tags using / not comma.  Then the tags appear in loggly in the tab on the left side.https://community.loggly.com/customer/en/portal/questions/9548214-how-to-add-tags-using-log4net-config-asp-net-?b_id=50&new=9548214

Comment: Unless I'm looking at a different support question, I think the link to it is now https://community.loggly.com/customer/portal/questions/4628556-how-do-i-send-host-and-application-using-loggly-api?b_id=50